# Product image not showing into after upload to server - magento-2 data migration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, product-images, magento2-migration-tool

Recently I have migrated the magento-1 (ver: 1.9.1.1) data to magento-2 (Ver: ver: 2.1.7) fress version using data migration tool. And it working perfectly in our local computer (localhost).

I found an issue after upload it to server [m2.hiddencamera.com.au](http://m2.hiddencamera.com.au) that some product image (thumbnail and in details view) not showing instead it showing blank image (http://m2.hiddencamera.com.au/hidden-cameras?cat=84).

[image: Product image showing in localhost]

Then I have removed the cache, reindex, upgrade (`setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex, cache:clean, cache:flush`) using SSH. Even I have flushed Catalog Images Cache for pregenerated product images files from Dashboard -> System -> Cache Management. But no luck.

After inspecting the blank image that the image (url) are not serving from `pub/media/catalog/product/cache/` instead it serving from `pub/static/`. But in localhost all product image source is `pub/media/catalog/product/cache/`.

Finally, I have contacted with the hosting support about the issue but, unfortunately they failed to fix the issue. They didn't found any error from error log. They also try to solve the issue using `setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex, cache:clean, cache:flush` etc but no luck.

I am requesting for help from the experts to resolve the issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not generated the Static View Files. The static view files refer to the files which are not generated dynamically. These files include images, CSS and JS files. These files are located in the `pub/static` directory of your Magento 2, and some are cached to the `var/view_preprocessed` directory as well.

The static view files must be written to the Magento 2 file system using the Command-Line Interface (CLI). To do so, first of all delete caches, sessions & old files that are generated before. To delete caches and sessions, navigate to the following paths and delete everything:

```
MAGENTO2_ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
MAGENTO2_ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
MAGENTO2_ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
MAGENTO2_ROOT > var > view_preprocessed > *DELETE ALL*
```

Also, remove everything including old generated static files from below path except `.htaccess` file:

```
MAGENTO2_ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS
```

Now finally to deploy static view files and re-index the indexers. Run the following CLI commands in Magento 2 root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

This might help you and solve the issue. You can also check out the below blog post and try the other solutions too:

[Fix Broken Magento 2 Installation](https://magenticians.com/fix-broken-magento-2-installation/)

Comment: Hi @Foyyaz,

Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried all the process but no luck. Anyway when checking the product cache image directory I found that the image is not generating for most of the product in server but it generating localhost. For that I am trying to re-generate the image using `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`.  But after starting the process in ssh a warning is showing that;  `Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file
in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 65` .

Comment: After google the issue most of the expert saying this problem may be for php memory_limit issue. I have increased the limit 768MB, but still it showing the warning..

Comment: You can also try by increasing max upload size and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have tested again after increasing the memory limit, but no luck :(

Comment: Think, the problem is for generating the images cache in server.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> Give permissions to pub/media folder chmod -R 777 pub/media/
```

Comment: This solution is not helping